# How to count the number of options in a select drop down box in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have Select Dropdown list with this:

```
xpath //*[@id="ddlTablePay"]
```

I need to count the number of options in this drop-down. Thank You

Comment: iterate it and simple increase counter by one

Comment: dont we have any inbuilt function for that?

Comment: Why haven't you accepted one of the answers?

Comment: As the element as ID, you should use ID instead of xpath. Because ID is more preferable than xpath.

Answer (score 11):

Use `.getOptions()` method and store them in a list .Then find its size.

```
Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select drop down locator")));

List<WebElement> l = se.getOptions();
l.size();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] options = driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown")).getText().split("\n");
options.length;
```

Comment: maybe elaborate on the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.getXpathCount()` method

```
int numOptions = selenium.getXpathCount("//*[@id='ddlTablePay']/option").intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
optionItems = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ddlTablePay']"))
print "Total Elements " + str(len(optionItems.options))
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of options

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlTablePay")));
List<WebElement> elementCount = dropDown.getOptions();
System.out.println("Number of items: " + elementCount.size());
```

To get and print all the Options

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlTablePay")));
        List <WebElement> elementCount = dropDown.getOptions();
        int itemSize = elementCount.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < itemSize ; i++){
            String optionsValue = elementCount.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(optionsValue);
        }
```

Comment: I have used ID instead of xpath though xpath also definitely works. ID is more preferable than xpath if any control/element has ID.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the xpath of the dropdown whose count you want:

```
static int getDropdownListCount(String xpath) {
        
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    Select select = new Select(element);
    List<WebElement> elements = select.getOptions();
    return elements.size();
}
```

It'll return count of total number of options under that dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below syntax to count the number of element in drop down list. First you need to read anyone element from drop down list as below.

```
String report1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of first element of dropdown list")).getText();

String [] element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your-xpath-complete drop down section")).getText().split("\n");

elements.length
```

elements.length is the number of elements present in your drop down list