# Is there any way to get directly last value of dropdown in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have dropdown as pagination and values are dynamic depends on data. Sometimes it can be 1 and if data are more then it can be 10 so I want to get last value of this dropdown in selenium webdriver.

I have checked 3 similar questions here on stack-overflow but not one has satisfied answer to get last option of dropdown using selenium webdriver & Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways how to get last option text

1) Find the last item with xpath or css selector and get text of it

```
xpath=//select/option[last()]
css_selector = select option:last-child
```

2) Use javascript or jquery

```
driver.execute_script( "return $('select option:last-child').text()")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you out : [Measure Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210853/how-to-count-the-number-of-options-in-a-select-dropdown-box-in-selenium)

You can measure the size of the dropdown list and take the last one. Hope i understand your problem.

Code Copy and paste:

```
Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select drop down locator")));

List<WebElement> l = se.getOptions();
l.size();
```